# Query for pattern separated by new lines

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I have a table (`defect` ) where a column stores a text. Each line in this text represents a version. (this is clearquest database running microsoft SQL, accessed via JDBC)

For example, following data represents three versions a fix is made.

```
defect version_fixed
1      2015.1.1
2      2015.1.1\n2015.1.13
3      2015.1.12\n2015.1.1 
4      2015.1.12\n2015.1.1\n2015.1.13 
5      2015.1.13\n2015.1.10 
5      2015.1.100
```

As you see the version is not stored in an order.  It can appear anywhere.

I am interested in all rows with fix version fixed containing "2015.1.1". But my query  either gets more rows or skips some

```
version_fixed like '%2016.1.1%' (gets row 5 as it matches the pattern)
version_fixed like '%2016.1.1\n'(does not get any thing.)
```

I am looking for query to get exact list for 2015.1.1

```
defect version_fixed
1      2015.1.1
2      2015.1.1\n2015.1.13
3      2015.1.12\n2015.1.1 
4      2015.1.12\n2015.1.1\n2015.1.13
```

How can I query where text matches with "exact string, delimited by new line or end of text". What is the correct way to escape new line?

Side note: Current solution is to get all records(including unwanted one and then filter out incorrect results)

Comment: `2015.1.1` should be at the beginning of the string or it can be any where else

Comment: Also add expected result when pass some x input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. It relies on Sql Server adding the newline to the string when you break the line.

```
create table defect( version_fixed varchar(max) )
insert into defect( version_fixed ) 
values ( '2015.1.1' )
, ( '2015.1.1
2015.1.13' )
, ( '2015.1.12
2015.1.1' )
, ( '2015.1.12
2015.1.1
2015.1.13')
, ( '2015.1.13
2015.1.10' )
, ( '2015.1.100' )

-- break to a new line and Sql Server will include the newline character in the string
select * from defect where version_fixed like '%2015.1.1
%' or version_fixed like '%2015.1.1'
```

Comment: this gave the idea.  Added  muiltiple extected  pattern(with additional new lines etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can as the below:

```
WHERE '\' + version_fixed  + '\' LIKE '%2015.1.1\%'
```

This solution depands on your sample data.